# How to center buttons in my java game menu

Tags: java, swing

So, basically, I've never really worked with windows in java, and I need help centering things. I tried a bunch of things, but no matter what, I can't center my buttons on my java menu.

Here's my main class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class window extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImage canvas;

    public window(int width, int height) {
        canvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g){ 
        
        
//          double CanvasTileHeight = (canvas.getHeight()/16)+1;
//          double CanvasTileWidth = (canvas.getWidth()/16)+1;
//          
//          OpenSimplexNoise noise = new OpenSimplexNoise();
//          
//          for(int j=0;j<CanvasTileWidth;j++) {
//              double NoiseForCurrentLoopPos;
//              if (((noise.eval(j,2)+1)*2)+16 < CanvasTileHeight) {
//                  NoiseForCurrentLoopPos = ((noise.eval(j,2)+1)*2)+16;
//              } else {
//                  NoiseForCurrentLoopPos = CanvasTileHeight;
//              }
//              for(int i=(int) CanvasTileHeight;i>NoiseForCurrentLoopPos;i--) {
//                      Image sand = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/images/misc/sand.png");
//                      g.drawImage(sand, j*16, i*16, this);                    
//              }
//          }
//          
//          Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/images/misc/Player_Placeholder1.png");
//          
//       ImageObserver paintingChild = null;
//       g.drawImage(image, canvas.getWidth()/2-image.getWidth(paintingChild)/2, canvas.getHeight()/2-image.getHeight(paintingChild)/2, this);
//          
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example Frame");

        window panel = new window(width, height);
        
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        
        BoxLayout boxlayout = new BoxLayout(buttons, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        buttons.setLayout(boxlayout);
        
        buttons.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(150, 200, 150, 200)));
        JLabel bottomLabel = new JLabel("GAME NAME HERE", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        buttons.add(bottomLabel);
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        jb1.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jb2.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jb3.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        buttons.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        buttons.add(jb1); 
        buttons.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        buttons.add(jb2);
        buttons.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        buttons.add(jb3);
        
        frame.add(buttons);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
//        loadtest();
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(((String) test1).split(",")));
//        
//        savetest();
        
        dirtest();
    }

    public static void savetest() {
        String TestArray[] = {"hi87er629087029648276540982", "hi2", "hi3", "hi4", "Not gonna keep going on like this lol"};
        String Test = TestArray[0];
        String world = "testworld101022";
        
        for (int k = 0; k < TestArray.length-1; k++) {
            Test = Test + "," + TestArray[k+1];
        }
        
        new File("src\\saves\\" + world).mkdir();
        try(FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("src\\saves\\" + world + "\\chunk1savetest1.txt");
                ObjectOutput s = new ObjectOutputStream(f)) {
                s.writeObject(Test);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    
    static Object test1 = null;
    
    public static void loadtest() {
        String world = "testworld101022";
        
        try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("src\\saves\\" + world + "\\chunk1savetest1.txt");
                ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(in)) {
                test1 = s.readObject();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    }
    
    public static void dirtest() {
        File dir = new File("src\\saves");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
           public boolean accept(File file) {
              return file.isDirectory();
           }
        };
        files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
        System.out.println(files.length);
        
        if (files.length == 0) {
           System.out.println("No saves yet!");
        } else {
           for (int i = 0; i< files.length; i++) {
              File filename = files[i];
              System.out.println(filename.toString());
           }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I run it, this is what happens:

[image]

So, the buttons and/or test are not centered. I don't understand why.

[image]

My problem is, the buttons should be about where the red line on the image is, but no matter what I do, I can't get it to work.

I tried centering it with `SwingConstants.CENTER`, but that diden't work, so I also tried `Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT`, but that did the exact same thing. I found that doing multiple different things like changing the code to

```
jb1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
jb2.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.CENTER);
jb3.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

makes it like this:

[image]

so basically it makes it so the 2 that are different from the one I changed are *correctly* centered, but the one I changed it not. All the images and stuff are probably unnecessary, but I hope I got across what I need help with! thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You can use BoxLayout to do that, take a look at the following code:

```
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("GAME NAME HERE");
        final JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        final JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        final JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");

        final JPanel centerPanel = createCenterVerticalPanel(5, label, button1, button2, button3);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(centerPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private static JPanel createCenterVerticalPanel(final int spaceBetweenComponents, final JComponent... components)
    {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        Arrays.stream(components).forEach(component -> {
            component.setAlignmentX(JPanel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            panel.add(component);
            panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, spaceBetweenComponents)));
        });

        return panel;
    }
}
```

If you also want to center a panel vertically in a frame, just use         `frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout())`. Cheers!

Comment: thank you so much! This fixed the problem I was having!